# Python incremente a number each second

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I incremente a number each second? I was thinking to something like this.

```
import  threading

def printit():
    second = 1
    while threading.Timer(1, printit).start(): #for every second that pass.
        print(second)
        second += 1

printit()
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your code?

Comment: @Kasramvd Nothing is being printed in the console. Also there are no errors and I am using PyShell

Comment: So what you are looking for?

Comment: "How can I incremente a number each second?" - OP

Comment: @Kasramvd I want this function to print the incremented number every second.

Comment: So you need to move the `Timer` out of the function or put it in another function, and use a  `while True` loop. Or use `for` loop with limited number of loops.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `asyncio` as well, it's basically built for exactly this kind of thing (well, a lot more, but)

Comment: Take a look at the `time()` function. Your desired number is just the offset between a starting value and the current `time()` value.

Comment: FYI, among other reasons, the reason this did nothing is that `while threading.Timer(1, printit).start():` is evaluating the result of `Timer.start()`, which is always `None`. So each time this function ran, it created a `Timer` to run itself again, evaluated the return value from `start()` as "falsy", then exited without incrementing or printing (and each time, it was starting with a fresh count of 0 for that matter). You spawned a `Timer` at the correct interval, it just did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a different method using `time.sleep(1)`, the solution would be:

```
from time import sleep
def printit():
...     cpt = 1
...     while True:
...         print cpt
...         sleep(1)
...         cpt+=1
```

> **time.sleep(secs)**
>
> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given
>   number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways of doing this. The first as others have suggested is

```
import time

def print_second():
    second = 0
    while True:
        second += 1
        print(second)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The problem with this method is that it halts execution of the rest of the program (unless it is running in another thread). The other way allows you to perform other processes in the same loop while still incriminating the second counter and printing it out every second.

```
import time

def print_second_new():
    second = 0
    last_inc = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() >= last_inc + 1:
            second += 1
            print(second)
            last_inc = time.time()
 #       <other code to loop through>
```